# Angular 7 & ionic 4 Router - Pass the method

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I am implmenting the angular router in the hybrid mobile application.(Upgrading from ionic 3 to 4). One my scnerio, I want to pass the method as a query parameter to another page. For example, Call the page "studentEditPage" from "Student Detail Page" and passing the "Update" method name to student edit page.  Before poping the "StudentEditPage", it calls the update method then pop. I am tring to pass the method in the queryparam in navigate but it does not accept it in ionic 4. Are we able to pass the method as a param in the queryparameters

From StudentDetailPage

```
  let navigationExtras : NavigationExtras = {
      state : {
        param : { detail: "editcategory", value: studentName, callback: this.updateStudentCallback, }
      }
    }
    that.router.navigate(['studentDetailsPage'],navigationExtras); Here "this.updateStudentCallback" as a method.
```

From StudentEditPage:

```
    this.updateStudentCallback(tempEmpData).then(() => {
    this.navigate.router(['studentEditPage'])
});
```

I have googled and searched the angular posts but unable to get the proper results. THanks in Advance.

Comment: `this.navCtrl.push("ArrivalpointPage",{selectedseats:this.selectedseats,});` .Here i am passing selectedseats information into ArrivalpointPage

Comment: @Juniorcoder, Thank you. But I am using the "Router" concepts not NavController since It has deprecated on the ionic 4. Any idea on the "Router"?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can id like this:

where you want send/pass id/param put id here on the `app-routing.module.ts` file

```
{ path: 'studentedit/:sid', loadChildren: './studentedit/studentedit.module#StudentEditPageModule'},
```

then in html file

```
<h1 (click)="gotoUpdate(std.studentID)" >click</h1>
```

in ts file

```
gotoProductlist(studentID: string) {
  this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/studentUpdate/' + studentID);
}
```

in Edit Page

```
ngOnInit() {
   // Get the ID that was passed with the URL
   let id = this.activatedroute.snapshot.paramMap.get('sid');
}
```

Well you can get id from another page.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to pass the "Method" as queryparamenter like,  if(page && dict) {
        let navigationExtras : NavigationExtras = {
          state : {
            param : { detail: "editcategory", value: studentName, callback: this.updateStudentCallback, }
          }
        }
        that.router.navigate('studentDetailsPage',navigationExtras); Here "this.updateStudentCallback" as a method.